# Debug Apache Cordova with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, apache-cordova

I have a simple question: can I debug Apache Cordova with VS Code?

I have simple installed and created an app(https://cordova.apache.org/) and then opened the app in VS Code, but I cannot debug it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, start up the app on your device / emulator / simulator of choice using. See the [TACO CLI](http://taco.tools) docs for help with pre-reqs... running is simple.

To debug, for Android 4.4+, you can just use Chrome Dev Tools. See [Chrome documentation on Remote Debugging Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/remote-debugging/remote-debugging). This works for Cordova apps too.

For iOS, you can do the same thing from Safari on your Mac. Check "Show Develop menu in menu bar" under Preferences.. >Advanced.  Then use the Develop menu to find your device and the cordova app running on it. Be sure to go to Settings > Safari > Advanced and enable the "Web Inspector" option on your device as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very much possible with the vscode-cordova extension. Install this extension to your VSCode and you should be able to debug the app running on iOS/Android device & simluators/emulators. More details on this is available at the VSCode-cordova github readme.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova

Comment: Is this also true for Windows OS?